# minimization of frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am looking for W which minimize  $$||W^TW-\lambda^2\mathbf{I}||_{\rm F}$$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is the $m$-dimensional identity matrix, $||\cdot ||_{\rm F}$ is the Frobenius-norm and $W\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ and $\lambda$  is constant.

I'd be grateful for all helpful advices or even solutions!

Comment: If $n \geq m$ then you can always get $0$ by taking $W$ to be the block matrix $( \lambda \mathrm{I} \quad 0_{m \times n-m} )^T$ as for that choice $W^T W = \lambda^2 \mathrm{I}$. The case where $n < m$ seems more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that $n \geq m$, the problem is trivial.

In the case that $n < m$, this can be easily solved as a consequence of the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem). In particular, we have
$$
\min \{\|X - \lambda^2 I\|_F : X = W^TW, W \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}\} \geq\\
\min\{\|X - \lambda^2 I\|_F : X \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}, \operatorname{rank}(X) \leq n\}.
$$
The EYM theorem tells us that the second minimum is attained with 
$$
X = \pmatrix{\lambda^2 I_n & 0\\0 & 0_{m \times m}}.
$$
We note that this minimum is achieved in the first set with $W = \pmatrix{\lambda I_n\\ 0}$.