# similarity to identity matrix

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I am looking for a way to determine how much matrix $W^TW$ is close to identity matrix($\lambda^2\mathbf{I}$ ).
suppose we just want to compare various $W$ matrices and find out which one is closer to identity matrix( in other words, having wider singular value spectrum)

I'd be grateful for all helpful advices or even solutions!

Comment: Why not just compute the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) between the two?

Comment: Do you mean frobenius norm?@Zim Also I don't know which $\lambda$ gives me the minimum value of the distance.

Comment: @MahshadJavidan See the answer to [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686940/minimization-of-frobenius-norm). If you are content with Frobenius distance, then the minimum distance attained is $\|W^TW - \lambda^2 I \|_F = \lambda^2 \sqrt{m-n}$.

Comment: The EYM theorem says that we have the same closest choice of $W$ for every unitarily invariant norm (e.g. the spectral norm and nuclear norm). The minimal distance is $\lambda^2$ for the spectral norm, and the minimal distance for the nuclear norm will be $\lambda^2(m-n)$

Comment: @MahshadJavidan You've been asking about this problem over several months now; it might be helpful to ask a more detailed question about the context in which this problem arises

Comment: @MahshadJavidan there are a bunch of ways to compute different notions of distance -- Frobenius norm of the difference is among them. It depends on how you want to define your problem. Frobenius is definitley a popular choice, but other norms are also used, depending on the problem context.